# Dynamic Badges GitHub

Tags: git, github, badge, readme, shields.io

I have been using [shields.io](http://shields.io) to build my GitHub badges in the README files, but only for badges such as license and version.

Now, **my goal** is to build dynamic badges on the number of watches of a specific repo, in a way that the number updates whenever a new person is watching the repo.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved the problem.

For the **repo** `Project-CodeIgniter-CMS` and **user** `goncaloperes`, I have used the following code:

Watches:

```
[![GitHub Watches](https://img.shields.io/github/watchers/goncaloperes/Project-CodeIgniter-CMS.svg?style=social&label=Watch&maxAge=2592000)](https://github.com/goncaloperes/Project-CodeIgniter-CMS/watchers)
```

Starts:

```
[![GitHub Starts](https://img.shields.io/github/stars/goncaloperes/Project-CodeIgniter-CMS.svg?style=social&label=Star&maxAge=2592000)](https://github.com/goncaloperes/Project-CodeIgniter-CMS/stargazers)
```

Forks:

```
[![GitHub Forks](https://img.shields.io/github/forks/goncaloperes/Project-CodeIgniter-CMS.svg?style=social&label=Fork&maxAge=2592000)](https://github.com/goncaloperes/Project-CodeIgniter-CMS/network)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shields.io do support watchers also as a badge type

```
![GitHub watchers](https://img.shields.io/github/watchers/badges/shields.svg?style=social&logo=github&label=Watch)
```